# Template class instantiation without angular brackets

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I was wondering whether this code is legal (in C++17, of course):

```
template<typename T = int>
class C {};

int main() {
    C c;
}
```

This compiles fine with GCC 8.1.0 but fails with Clang 6.0.0. I tried to find an answer in the Standard, but I'm no language lawyer and I couldn't figure it out. On the other hand, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) states this:

```
std::less l;             // same as std::less<void> l;
```

So, is it possible to define an object, whose type is a template class where all template parameters have got a default, without using the *angular brackets*?

**EDIT**

I try to clarify my doubt: my code, with a slight edit, i.e. changing the `main`'s body to

```
C<> c;
```

is legal code from C++98. Where, in the C++17 Standard, we may argue that the *empty angular brackets* are no more mandatory in this case?

Comment: Most likely this is just a bug/lack of functionality.  It compiles on 7.1 and above.  IIRC gcc 6.0 predates C++17 by about a year.

Comment: [p0620r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0620r0.html) clarifies that CTAD happens in the default-initialization case. Before that an initializer is required.

Answer (score 4):

> So, is it possible to define an object, whose type is a template class where all template parameters have got a default, without using the square brackets?

The short answer is yes. The whole mechanism is similar (and in fact is based on) function template argument deduction. When deducing the template arguments of a class template, the deduction guides (both user-provided and compiler generated) are considered through an overload resolution process similar to what we have for function calls.

So you *can* do what you want, for the same reason this is valid:

```
template<typename T = void>
void foo() {}

int main() {
  foo();
}
```

We call `foo` without angle brackets, and `T` is `void` since it isn't deduced and has to be taken from the default argument.

Comment: I've edited my original question, trying to clarify my doubt; your code is legal C++11 code, because of the introduction of default template arguments for functions. I'm trying to understand what in the C++17 standard may (or may not) make legal my code.

Comment: @PaoloM - I'm sorry, but I don't think SO is the correct platform to re-iterate verbatim the proposal for CTAD. I know your code sample *seems* small but it moves a lot of machinery. And when you specify `C<>` it no longer moves *that machinery*, it moves the mechanism present since the early editions of C++. I'd also avoid making any blanket statements like *"empty square brackets are no more mandatory in this case"*. This is complex, and you may get entirely different types with or without the brackets.

Comment: I respect (and partly agree with) your opinion, but I've seen tons of _standard oriented_ questions on SO as of today. The last part of your comment is interesting, though: what do you mean with "you may get entirely different types with or without the brackets"? You mean that in some cases I may get different deduced types with `C<> c;` or `C c;`? I mean, even with empty brackets?

Comment: @PaoloM - Yes. [Take this example for instance](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5d26350f1de8de3). The defaults are the only thing being considered if the brackets are there. This is unlike with functions, where the brackets are truly just optional when everything can be deduced.

Comment: @PaoloM - And regarding standard oriented questions, I've given a few such answers myself. But sometimes, it really is too much to bring into the discussion. Unsurprisingly, whenever I reach that conclusion about a question, templates are involved. I'm hoping that an explanation without a wall of standardese will help future readers. At the very least help them get a feel for this feature if nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

Class template argument deduction is performed through an initialization of an object of a hypothetical class type:

```
class hypothetical_C {
    template <typename T = int>
    hypothetical_C();

    // other constructors
};
```

according to [[over.match.class.deduct]/1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1):

> When resolving a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]) where the template-name names a primary class template C, a set of functions and function templates is formed comprising:
>
> - If C is defined, for each constructor of C, a function template with the following properties:
>
>   - The template parameters are the template parameters of C followed by the template parameters (**including default template arguments**) of the constructor, if any.
>   - The types of the function parameters are those of the constructor.
>   - The return type is the class template specialization designated by C and template arguments corresponding to the template parameters of C.
> - ...

and [[over.match.class.deduct]/2](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#2):

> Initialization and overload resolution are performed as described in [dcl.init] and [over.match.ctor], [over.match.copy], or [over.match.list] (as appropriate for the type of initialization performed) for an object of a hypothetical class type, where the selected functions and function templates are considered to be the constructors of that class type for the purpose of forming an overload set, and the initializer is provided by the context in which class template argument deduction was performed.

[Since there is no initializer](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#12), the object is [default-initialized](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#2), thus the constructor template specialization `hypothetical_C<int>()` is selected. At last, according to [[dcl.type.class.deduct]/1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.class.deduct#1):

> If a placeholder for a deduced class type appears as a decl-specifier in the decl-specifier-seq of an initializing declaration ([dcl.init]) of a variable, **the placeholder is replaced by the return type of the function selected by overload resolution for class template deduction** ([over.match.class.deduct]).

the class template argument is deduced to be `int`.